# Finding which process was killed by Linux OOM killer

Tags: linux

When Linux runs out of memory (OOM), the OOM killer chooses a process to kill based on some heuristics (it's an interesting read: http://lwn.net/Articles/317814/).

How can one *programmatically* determine which processes have recently been killed by the OOM killer?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Try this out:

```
grep -i 'killed process' /var/log/messages
```

Comment: FWIW, I get those messages in syslog, or kern.log, but not /var/log/messages

Comment: You can use "egrep -i -r 'killed process' /var/log/" to search it also in other places.

Comment: @jberryman: For some reason, syslog is in `/var/log/syslog` on some distros, and `/var/log/messages` on others. I think it's Debian for the former and Red Hat for the latter, BICBW.

Comment: " dmesg | egrep -i 'killed process' "   and you can search logs anywhere (including archived ones) :)

Comment: `egrep` doesn't make sense here.  Plain old `grep`, or if we're being specific, `fgrep`, makes much more sense.  (Editing answer accordingly.)

Comment: The precise location depends on the logging arcitecture and its configuration. `/etc/syslog.conf` is a good place to start looking, though on some arcane systems, this too could be in a different location.

Answer (score 250):

Try this so you don't need to worry about where your logs are:

```
dmesg -T | egrep -i 'killed process'
```

`-T, --ctime` - Print human-readable timestamps.

Comment: This is also useful, but while I unfortunately can't explain it, I'm seeing results in `/var/log/messages` that aren't showing up in `dmesg`/`/var/log/dmesg`. It could be some sort of misconfiguration, but worth noting that using both approaches could be a good idea.

Comment: Not sure about your log file, but the output of dmesg is from a limited-size ring buffer.  If other things have filled the buffer since the oom-killer then you'll lose the oom-killer output.

Comment: This was the only way I found how to see that process was killed in OpenVZ container

Comment: Compared to /var/log/messages, this has the advantages of not requiring root privileges

Comment: For me it was just at the bottom of dmesg -T.  I didn't need to grep.

Comment: Please keep in mind `dmesg` is for `kernel ring buffer`, not the messages before start or reboot

Answer (score 61):

Now dstat provides the feature to find out in your running system which process is candidate for getting killed by oom mechanism

```
dstat --top-oom
 --out-of-memory---
  kill score
 java           77
 java           77
 java           77
```

and as per man page

```
  --top-oom
          show process that will be killed by OOM the first
```

Comment: This info is meaningless without knowing what the score means, and that's not documented anywhere. All you might see is the score increase, then the process being killed, so maybe it was the oom killer, or maybe it was something else, there's no way to be sure.

Comment: Where does `dstat` read this kill score data from? (A file?) Edit: Just found: `/proc/<PID>/oom_score`

Answer (score 26):

Try this out:

```
grep "Killed process" /var/log/syslog
```