# What causes an R script to get Killed?

Tags: r

I've been running some memory intensive processes on EC2 servers. The code runs quite well for about 12-14 hours (it's running 1000s of simulations on 12-14 large datasets) and then all of a sudden I just see the message "Killed" with no further explanation.

What makes R do that?

UPDATE: [My server specs.](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?categoryID=223&externalID=2053)

Comment: What are you running the script on?

Comment: An Amazon EC2 server running ubuntu with 67 gigs of RAM.

Comment: Can you split your problem into smaller chunks? This would allow you to save the bits of analysis that work, and narrow down the place where the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 14):

It could be the [out of memory killer](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2009/09/30/how-the-linux-oom-killer-works/) of the operating system.

Are you cleaning up your workspace when you have finished with a dataset?

Comment: I verified it was the OOM killer on Ubuntu that killed my R process by checking the last OOM killed processes using `dmesg -T | egrep -i 'killed process' ` cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624857/finding-which-process-was-killed-by-linux-oom-killer

Answer (score 5):

From what I know, I don't think R has a "killed" error. Most likely it's your operating system imposing a process limit or some kind of quotas. If you are working on a network system, maybe ask your sysadmin?

Comment: The entire server is mine. I have no limits so to speak. It's a server with 67 gigs of RAM and I batch the scripts so more than one isn't running at a time. So I am a little puzzled why it quits without further explanation. I source the script from within R.

Comment: Hum... https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-April/049212.html, afaik R doesn't have Killed as an error though... are you sure there isn't any default process limits? I'd check your settings. Also, make sure you aren't using the 32bit version of R, and check how much memory your installation of ubuntu sees with the free command

Comment: No problem, I hope you can resolve your issue some time soon.

Comment: I just ran an R script and it said "Killed", so yeah, it's got one...10 years after this question was posed.