# How to find the process that killed a running java VM

Tags: java, notifications

I'm facing a situation where one of my java VMs is being killed by some other process and the java VM exits with an exit status of 143. Is there any way I can find the process which killed my program?
I read about Runtime.addShutdownHook but I found it of no use. Though I can find when my process is being killed, I can't find who's killing it. 
What I need is a Holmes to find the killer.
I'm using Sun JDK and the acommpanying JRE btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're using linux, check your logs to see if the kernel is killing children again. OOM killer..

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been here for a while but in case others are looking for a solution. To expand on Jw's answer. Check the `/var/log/kern.log`, `/var/log/messages`, or `/var/log/syslog` files.

More info about processes being killed can be found in the following threads.

[Finding which process was killed by Linux OOM killer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624857/finding-which-process-was-killed-by-linux-oom-killer)

[Who "Killed" my process and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why)