# How to determine what kills my Java server in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, kill

I have a Java server running on an Ubuntu machine and every few days it just... dies. Every exit point on every thread leaves a log entry and everything is wrapped in try-catch with a log entry in the catch, but on these mysterious shutdowns, nothing gets logged.

I launch the server with a simple nohup java -jar MyServer.jar command.

One time, I had a terminal I launched it from still open when this happened and the word "KILLED" showed up there. Note that, when I kill the server myself with a kill command from another terminal, nothing shows up.

How do I determine what killed it?

Comment: It might have been the OOM killer; http://stackoverflow.com/q/624857/166749

Comment: This sounds more like a question for serverfault.com

Comment: You can add a SecurityManager which logs any attempt to call System.exit() but it sounds like a signal is killing your process.

Comment: Do you have swap defined on your machine? Is there a chance that the process memory is growing and there is not enough memory on your machine?

Comment: It was the OOM killer, as larsmans suggested.