# Tomcat 7 crashes on ubuntu server every few hours

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I have ubuntu server 12.04 installed on a VM with tomcat 7 installed, My problem is that tomcat crashes every few hours (2-5) for no clear reason (no exceptions or errors in catalina logs or my logs). I checked all the other logs and found this in the kernel logs. I don't know if it has any significance

```
kernel: [30064.700119] send sigkill to 3188 (java), adj 0, size 48551
```

I searched and read that it is usually a memory problem, but I am not sure how to know the exact cause.

Comment: Could be the OOMkiller killing your runaway tomcat process.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: noobuntu, server? now that's an oxymoron...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624857/finding-which-process-was-killed-by-linux-oom-killer

Comment: @Bart I already tried it(with syslog and kern.log), and no mesaages were returned