# Rake Task killed probably by out-of-memory issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-management, rake-task

I have a `rake task` and when I run it in console, it is `killed`. This `rake task` operates with a table of cca `40.000 rows`, I guess that may be a problem with [Out of memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory).

Also, I believe that this query used is optimized for dealing with long tables:

```
MyModel.where(:processed => false).pluck(:attribute_for_analysis).find_each(:batch_size => 100)   do |a|

# deal with 40000 rows and only attribute `attribute_for_analysis`.

end
```

This task will not be run in the future on regular basis, so I want to avoid some job monitoring solutions like `God` etc...but considering `background jobs` e.g.[Rescue job](https://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque).

I work with `Ubuntu`, `ruby 2.0` and `rails 3.2.14`

```
> My free memory is as follows: 


Mem:                total      used       free     shared    buffers     cached  
                    3891076    1901532    1989544  0         1240        368128
-/+ buffers/cache:  1532164    2358912
Swap:               4035580     507108    3528472
```

---

**QUESTIONS**:

1. How to investigate why `rake task is always killed` (answered)
2. How to make this `rake task` running ( not answered - still is killed )
3. What is the difference between `total-vm`, `aton-rs`, `file-rss` (not answered)

---

**UPDATE 1**

-Can someone explain the difference between?:

> - total-vm
> - anon-rss
> - file-rss

```
$ grep "Killed process" /var/log/syslog 

Dec 25 13:31:14 Lenovo-G580 kernel: [15692.810010] Killed process 10017 (ruby) total-vm:5605064kB, anon-rss:3126296kB, file-rss:988kB
Dec 25 13:56:44 Lenovo-G580 kernel: [17221.484357] Killed process 10308 (ruby) total-vm:5832176kB, anon-rss:3190528kB, file-rss:1092kB
Dec 25 13:56:44 Lenovo-G580 kernel: [17221.498432] Killed process 10334 (ruby-timer-thr) total-vm:5832176kB, anon-rss:3190536kB, file-rss:1092kB
Dec 25 15:03:50 Lenovo-G580 kernel: [21243.138675] Killed process 11586 (ruby) total-vm:5547856kB, anon-rss:3085052kB, file-rss:1008kB
```

**UPDATE 2**

- modified query like this and `rake task` is still killed.

> ```
>  MyModel.where(:processed => false).find_in_batches   do |group|   
>  p system("free -k")
>  group.each do |row|    # process
>    end 
>  end
> ```

Comment: could you insert counter into loop and some memory minitor with `system` method?

Comment: `MyModel.where(:processed => false).pluck(:attribute_for_analysis).find_in_batches(:batch_size => 1000)   do |group|
  p system("free -k")
  group.each { |model| #your stuff }
end`

Comment: Try find in logs if it really was OOM killer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624857/finding-which-process-was-killed-by-linux-oom-killer

Comment: Also, I don't think your code does what you want. `pluck` returns an array, which doesn't have `find_each` method.

Comment: @cutalion updated question for my `log`..hm but I am note what the message means ...

Comment: print output of Update 2

Comment: there is no output, rake task is killed.(because of memory.Now `cached` is cca 1304M

Comment: @maro30, could you post all the code? Have you tried run it on smaller amount of records? `limit(1)`, `limit(10)`, `limit(100)`, `limit(1000)`. How soon task gets killed after start?