# npm install does not install nested dependancies

Tags: npm, ubuntu-14.04, dependency-management

`npm install` is failing to install all nested dependencies (seemingly from a depth of 2 packages deep and beyond).
I suspected it might have something to do with one or more dependencies (e.g. bcrypt) which error on install and kill the npm process (despite themselves seeming to install successfully).

Running `npm install` again does not install all the dependencies and you have to manually invoke `npm install <one of your packages>@<it's version number>` which is a bad thing.

$ npm -v
2.14.12

Works fine on Mac OSX.  Problem is on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

** Edit 1:  package.json **

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Test",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "0.8.5",
    "boom": "^3.1.2",
    "deep-freeze": "0.0.1",
    "good": "~6.4.0",
    "good-console": "~5.2.0",
    "hapi": "~11.1.2",
    "hapi-auth-cookie": "^3.1.0",
    "inert": "~3.2.0",
    "iron": "^4.0.0",
    "joi": "^8.0.4",
    "jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "kerberos": "0.0.17",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "moment": "^2.11.2",
    "mysql": "^2.10.2",
    "q": "~1.4.1",
    "react": "0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "0.14.6",
    "react-redux": "4.0.6",
    "react-router": "2.0.0-rc5",
    "react-router-redux": "2.1.0",
    "reduce-reducers": "0.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.0.5",
    "request": "2.69.0",
    "sequelize": "git://github.com/ajamesphillips/sequelize.git",
    "sparkpost": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

I have upgraded the server from 0.5 Gb RAM to 2 Gb RAM and so far it seems `npm install` proceeds smoothly.  Not certain that memory exhaustion was the problem.  Will hopefully not report back but will do if it breaks again.

Comment: What is your `package.json`? You are probably right -- a failed binary build or a post-install script can possibly kill `npm install` process,  or drop it into a  strange state. Are you getting any errors in your log?

Comment: Thanks @lxe  Have added `package.json`.  Problem seems to be solved by moving to large instance.  Not convinced yet though.  Also weirdly often npm couldn't even produce a `npm-debug.log`.  And when it could it just had the output from the npm install which a couple of times showed `kerberos`, `bcrypt` or something else hitting OOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this was an issue with running out of memory.  Will use `egrep -i -r 'killed process' /var/log/` ( [Finding which process was killed by Linux OOM killer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624857/finding-which-process-was-killed-by-linux-oom-killer) ) next time I have this problem to see if OOM killer killed some of the processes launched by npm install.