# Spring boot stops after starting on server

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot

When I trying to deploy jar file on server at that time it is deployed successfully and then I execute startup.sh file after that spring boot application is start the execution but after execute bellow logs server is not responding any more.

```
[2016-07-15 11:01:38.714] boot - 14956  INFO [main] --- TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer: Tomcat started on port(s): 8084 (http)
[2016-07-15 11:01:38.723] boot - 14956  INFO [main] --- Application: Started Application in 64.717 seconds (JVM running for 67.138)
[2016-07-15 11:01:44.688] boot - 14956  INFO [Thread-4] --- AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext: Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@64375c2a: startup date [Fri Jul 15 11:00:38 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2016-07-15 11:01:44.692] boot - 14956  INFO [Thread-4] --- DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Stopping beans in phase 0
[2016-07-15 11:01:44.752] boot - 14956  INFO [Thread-4] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
[2016-07-15 11:01:44.810] boot - 14956  INFO [Thread-4] --- LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean: Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Also attached screenshot here.

[image]

Please Guide,
Thanks.

Comment: Take a thread dump using the command kill -3 <your_pid> , so we will get more clarity what is going underneath.

Comment: I'd guess it's Linux's out of memory killer that's stopping the process. This will help you figure out if that's the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624857/finding-which-process-was-killed-by-linux-oom-killer#624868

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Maven add this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It should work.

Comment: sorry for late. so maybe system ram caused this. how much ram do you have and what is the load?

Comment: Hi , Initially I use 512mb space server , then I move to 2gb then its works fine now.

Comment: okay watch your memory always. so you know java needs more resource sometimes. have a nice day!