# Cannot start sonarqube because of memory problem

Tags: shell, sonarqube, centos7

I'm setting SonarQube in my CentOS 7 following this tutorial: https://thegeeksalive.com/how-to-install-sonarqube-on-centos/

And finally I start my Sonar, but it cannot start because of memory problem here.

```sh
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2019.07.24 10:58:55 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2019.07.24 10:58:55 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2019.07.24 10:58:55 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2019.07.24 10:58:55 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2019.07.24 10:58:55 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.07.24 10:58:55 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2019.07.24 10:59:08 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2019.07.24 10:59:08 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [/opt/sonarqube]: /usr/java/jdk-11.0.4/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/common/*:/opt/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process16556217505100103896properties
2019.07.24 10:59:12 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is stopped
2019.07.24 10:59:12 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143
2019.07.24 10:59:12 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2019.07.24 10:59:12 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Hope everyone help me find the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128166/sonarqube-exits-with-143) SOq question.

Comment: Seem duplicate but I've tried and no more useful!

Answer (score 0):

Check what's in `logs/es.log` in your SonarQube home directory. Many issues with starting SonarQube on Linux show messages such as `max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]`

If you see this, then you should run the following commands before starting SonarQube

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
sysctl -w fs.file-max=65535
```

Comment: I did it before but don't gain any success. May I must change another CentOS server?

Comment: Can you share details of what's appearing in your `es.log` please? It will make it easier to diagnose your actual failure.

Comment: This's content in es.log file bro.

Comment: That's not your es.log, that's the sonar.log file

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to use docker compose to start sonarqube service.
you can try with this.

1. append vm.max_map_count=655360 to /etc/sysctl.conf
2. $sysctl -p
3. retry again

Answer (score 0):

In my case setting `security_opt` in docker compose helped:

```
services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:10.2.1-community
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    (...)
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is most likely caused by the project being too big for SonarQube to scan with the default memory settings.

Try the following workarounds:

1. Increase the Java heap size on your system:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1g"
```

2. Update the javaOpts property in $SONARQUBE_HOME/conf/sonar.properties to grant more memory.

Comment: The user's error message indicates Sonar server failed to start, so they're not even at the point of scanning a project.