# cron killed by system

Tags: ubuntu, cron

My cron service keep killed by OS around 2-3 day after start which really frustrating, but seems no one encounter with this situation(nothing learn from google). Can you advice how to trace this issue?

1. This behavior is random, no explicit date and time. This time killed on 00:00:01.
2. resources is enough.

```
09:55:01 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
10:05:01 PM     all      2.45      0.00      4.04      0.06      0.00     93.45
10:15:01 PM     all      1.27      0.00      3.98      0.00      0.00     94.74
10:25:01 PM     all      1.46      0.00      3.96      0.01      0.00     94.58
10:35:01 PM     all      1.35      0.00      4.06      0.05      0.00     94.55
10:45:01 PM     all      1.30      0.00      4.11      0.00      0.00     94.59
10:55:01 PM     all      1.26      0.00      4.11      0.00      0.00     94.63
11:05:01 PM     all      1.27      0.00      4.11      0.00      0.00     94.61
11:15:01 PM     all      1.29      0.00      4.09      0.00      0.00     94.62
11:25:01 PM     all      1.29      0.00      4.03      0.00      0.00     94.67
11:35:02 PM     all      1.28      0.00      4.01      0.00      0.00     94.71
11:45:01 PM     all      1.27      0.00      4.03      0.00      0.00     94.70
11:55:01 PM     all      1.27      0.00      4.03      0.00      0.00     94.71
11:59:01 PM     all      1.27      0.00      4.04      0.00      0.00     94.68
12:00:01 AM     all      1.23      0.00      4.08      0.00      0.00     94.69
Average:        all      1.29      0.00      4.12      0.01      0.00     94.58
```

```
09:55:01 PM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit  kbactive   kbinact   kbdirty
10:05:01 PM    188444   1702008     90.03    162168    421180   1900536    100.53   1345564    203788         4
10:15:01 PM    188172   1702280     90.05    162168    421184   1902904    100.66   1346432    203604         4
10:25:01 PM    185436   1705016     90.19    162240    421276   1900980    100.56   1349056    203232         0
10:35:01 PM    184816   1705636     90.22    162240    421480   1901204    100.57   1349884    203040         4
10:45:01 PM    184592   1705860     90.24    162240    421484   1903888    100.71   1350236    202816         4
10:55:01 PM    185644   1704808     90.18    162244    421488   1900008    100.51   1349720    202700         4
11:05:01 PM    185392   1705060     90.19    162244    421492   1899364    100.47   1349668    202580         4
11:15:01 PM    184740   1705712     90.23    162244    421500   1903640    100.70   1350164    202524         4
11:25:01 PM    184844   1705608     90.22    162244    421504   1901208    100.57   1350088    202416         4
11:35:02 PM    184656   1705796     90.23    162244    421508   1902928    100.66   1350940    202320         4
11:45:01 PM    184440   1706012     90.24    162244    421516   1902392    100.63   1350564    202308         4
11:55:01 PM    184968   1705484     90.22    162244    421524   1899148    100.46   1350128    202292         4
11:59:01 PM    185064   1705388     90.21    162244    421528   1900400    100.53   1350100    202268         4
12:00:01 AM    182740   1707712     90.33    162244    421532   1907832    100.92   1352400    202244         4
Average:       186998   1703454     90.11    162546    426534   1900233    100.52   1322833    224168         5
```

3. no error mentioned in syslog.

```
Dec 18 23:59:01 localhost CRON[32201]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 60 2)
Dec 19 00:00:01 localhost CRON[1147]: (root) CMD (/tmp/.X17-unix/.rsync/c/aptitude>/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 19 00:00:01 localhost CRON[1149]: (wp) CMD (/var/lib/docker/volumes/root_wp_data/_data/.bashtemp/a/upd>/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 19 00:00:01 localhost CRON[1148]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib/armbian/armbian-apt-updates)
Dec 19 00:00:01 localhost CRON[1150]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib/armbian/armbian-truncate-logs)
Dec 19 00:00:01 localhost CRON[1153]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew)
Dec 19 00:00:01 localhost CRON[1152]: (root) CMD (/root/.nullcache/a/upd>/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 19 00:00:01 localhost CRON[1158]: (wp) CMD (/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/aptitude>/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 19 00:00:01 localhost systemd[1]: cron.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Dec 19 00:00:01 localhost systemd[1]: cron.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 19 00:00:01 localhost systemd[1]: cron.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Dec 19 00:58:57 localhost dhclient[2585]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.11 on wlan0 to 192.168.1.1 port 67 (xid=0x5584c9ee)
Dec 19 02:08:42 localhost dhclient[2585]: message repeated 312 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.11 on wlan0 to 192.168.1.1 port 67 (xid=0x5584c9ee)]
```

4. service log

```
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2019-12-19 00:00:01 HKT; 22h ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
  Process: 2176 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cron -f $EXTRA_OPTS (code=killed, signal=KILL)
 Main PID: 2176 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
    Tasks: 17
   Memory: 125.9M
      CPU: 10h 42min 23.763s
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           ├─ 1185 /bin/bash ./run
           ├─ 1252 /bin/bash ./go
           ├─ 3863 /bin/bash ./run
           ├─10646 rsync
           ├─10647 rsync
           ├─18403 /bin/bash ./go
           ├─18774 sleep 3
           ├─18779 sleep 3
           ├─18780 sleep 3
           ├─18782 sleep 3
           ├─18800 sleep 3
           ├─19727 /bin/bash ./go
           ├─24144 /bin/bash ./run
           ├─24926 /bin/bash ./go
           ├─26147 /bin/bash ./run
           ├─29234 /bin/bash ./go
           └─30797 /bin/bash ./run

Dec 19 00:00:01 aml CRON[1150]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib/armbian/armbian-truncate-logs)
Dec 19 00:00:01 aml CRON[1142]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 19 00:00:01 aml CRON[1153]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew)
Dec 19 00:00:01 aml CRON[1145]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user wp by (uid=0)
Dec 19 00:00:01 aml CRON[1152]: (root) CMD (/root/.nullcache/a/upd>/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 19 00:00:01 aml CRON[1143]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec 19 00:00:01 aml CRON[1158]: (wp) CMD (/tmp/.X19-unix/.rsync/c/aptitude>/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 19 00:00:01 aml systemd[1]: cron.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Dec 19 00:00:01 aml systemd[1]: cron.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 19 00:00:01 aml systemd[1]: cron.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

Comment: Is OOM-killer triggered? Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624857/finding-which-process-was-killed-by-linux-oom-killer

Comment: @YingyuYOU no luck, the syslog is attached in the question

Comment: [crond64/tsm virus in Ubuntun here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115770/crond64-tsm-virus-in-ubuntu)
Hi. You are hacked. See this for reference :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your account was compromised (I had the similar issue just couple of days ago). Look at this for quik solution: [crond64/tsm virus in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115770/crond64-tsm-virus-in-ubuntu).

And also very good detailed report (in Russian): [Тайная жизнь Linux сервера или веерная брутфорс атака на подсистему SSH](https://pcnews.ru/blogs/[iz_pesocnicy]_tajnaa_zizn_linux_servera_ili_veernaa_brutfors_ataka_na_podsistemu_ssh-950996.html), translated as something like: [The secret life of a Linux server or fan brute force attack on the SSH subsystem](https://pcnews.ru/blogs/[iz_pesocnicy]_tajnaa_zizn_linux_servera_ili_veernaa_brutfors_ataka_na_podsistemu_ssh-950996.html).