# ElasticSearch is being constantly killed

Tags: elasticsearch

I am tearing my hair trying to figure why ElasticSearch is not starting. These are my first days with ES stack, so I am completely helpless.
I am running

```
sudo systemctrl start elasticsearch
```

and get error saying that

> Job for elasticsearch.service failed because a fatal signal was
> delivered to the control process. See "systemctl status
> elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

When I try to run `journalctl -xe`, I see lines of super-unclear messages for me:

```
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB kernel: br-6f050fa6218c: port 2(veth19babe9) entered blocking state
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB kernel: br-6f050fa6218c: port 2(veth19babe9) entered disabled state
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB kernel: device veth19babe9 entered promiscuous mode
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB charon[1828]: 10[KNL] interface veth19babe9 activated
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB NetworkManager[757]: <info>  [1619021784.2920] manager: (veth8fd9f3d): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/423)
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB systemd-udevd[39880]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB NetworkManager[757]: <info>  [1619021784.2934] manager: (veth19babe9): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/424)
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB kernel: br-6f050fa6218c: port 2(veth19babe9) entered blocking state
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB kernel: br-6f050fa6218c: port 2(veth19babe9) entered forwarding state
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB systemd-udevd[39880]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB systemd-udevd[39880]: veth19babe9: Could not generate persistent MAC: No data available
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB systemd-udevd[39877]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB dockerd[1804]: time="2021-04-21T19:16:24.298236681+03:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using def>
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB dockerd[1804]: time="2021-04-21T19:16:24.298287953+03:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 200>
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB systemd-udevd[39877]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB systemd-udevd[39877]: veth8fd9f3d: Could not generate persistent MAC: No data available
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB containerd[851]: time="2021-04-21T19:16:24.328926349+03:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.cont>
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB charon[1828]: 11[KNL] interface veth8fd9f3d deleted
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB kernel: eth0: renamed from veth8fd9f3d
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth19babe9: link becomes ready
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB NetworkManager[757]: <info>  [1619021784.8637] device (veth19babe9): carrier: link connected
Apr 21 19:16:24 my-pc-15IKB gnome-shell[5088]: Removing a network device that was not added
Apr 21 19:16:26 my-pc-15IKB avahi-daemon[748]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface veth19babe9.IPv6 with address fe80::a0c2:a3ff:feb8:587a.
Apr 21 19:16:26 my-pc-15IKB charon[1828]: 12[KNL] fe80::a0c2:a3ff:feb8:587a appeared on veth19babe9
Apr 21 19:16:26 my-pc-15IKB avahi-daemon[748]: New relevant interface veth19babe9.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 21 19:16:26 my-pc-15IKB avahi-daemon[748]: Registering new address record for fe80::a0c2:a3ff:feb8:587a on veth19babe9.*.
```

My .yml file looks this:

```
cluster.name: petlon-app
node.name: my-app-node
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200
discovery.type: single-node
```

Could you please give a hint why does that mean ?

UPDATE:
The output of `sudo journalctl -u elasticsearch.service`

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2021-03-11 13:10:55 MSK, end at Wed 2021-04-21 21:11:37 MSK. --
мар 16 21:23:20 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
мар 16 21:23:41 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
мар 16 21:23:41 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
мар 16 21:23:41 my-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
-- Reboot --
апр 11 15:55:31 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
апр 11 15:55:46 my-pc systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
апр 11 15:56:41 my-pc systemd[1]: Stopping Elasticsearch...
апр 11 15:56:41 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Succeeded.
апр 11 15:56:41 my-pc systemd[1]: Stopped Elasticsearch.
апр 11 15:56:41 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
апр 11 15:57:01 my-pc systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
апр 11 16:11:06 my-pc systemd[1]: Stopping Elasticsearch...
апр 11 16:11:07 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Succeeded.
апр 11 16:11:07 my-pc systemd[1]: Stopped Elasticsearch.
-- Reboot --
апр 11 16:12:53 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
апр 11 16:13:13 my-pc systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
апр 11 18:51:08 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
апр 11 18:51:08 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
апр 11 21:31:42 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
апр 11 21:31:47 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
апр 11 21:31:47 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
апр 11 21:31:47 my-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
апр 11 21:32:14 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
апр 11 21:32:16 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
апр 11 21:32:16 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
апр 11 21:32:16 my-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
апр 11 21:35:33 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
апр 11 21:35:37 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
апр 11 21:35:37 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
апр 11 21:35:37 my-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
апр 11 21:37:53 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
апр 11 21:37:57 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
апр 11 21:37:57 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
апр 11 21:37:57 my-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
апр 11 21:38:02 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
апр 11 21:38:06 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
апр 11 21:38:06 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
апр 11 21:38:06 my-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
апр 11 21:41:57 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
апр 11 21:42:00 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
апр 11 21:42:00 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
апр 11 21:42:00 my-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
апр 11 21:46:53 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
апр 11 21:46:59 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
апр 11 21:46:59 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
апр 11 21:46:59 my-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
апр 11 21:49:00 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
апр 11 21:49:03 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
апр 11 21:49:03 my-pc systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
апр 11 21:49:03 my-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
апр 11 21:49:32 my-pc systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
```

Comment: Are there any elasticsearch logs in `/var/log/elasticsearch`?

Comment: It's totally empty

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: A SIGKILL(9) being received is very suspicious! It could be the Out of memory killer (maybe), can you try some of these steps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624857/finding-which-process-was-killed-by-linux-oom-killer